# Stop maven dependency from getting further inherited to children

Tags: maven, maven-dependency

Say we have the following dependency hierarchy in maven:

```
 +- projectA
 |  +- projectB
 |  |  +- projectC
 |  |  +- projectD
```

Here projectB needs certain libraries from projectA (let's say libX).
But, those libraries are not needed any further in the hierarchy (*ie.* C and D don't need libX).
Now, as projectC and projectE are inheriting all the dependencies from their parent project (projectA), so they can provide  for such dependency.

**Q.** Can we restrict the dependency inheritance at the level of projectB itself, so that we need not exclude it manually everywhere (viz. projectC, projectD, etc.)

Comment: If projectA is a project which contains code or even a dependency than is something wrong. Parent are only packaging type `pom` and never contain code. If in that pom a dependency is defined that's simply wrong...General rule never define dependencies in a parent....

Answer (score 1):

You can try using optional dependencies in projectB, this is the exact use-case :

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

In your pom something like :

```
    <project>
      ...
      <dependencies>
        <!-- declare the dependency to be set as optional -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
          <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
          <optional>true</optional> <!-- value will be true or false only -->
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `<optional>true</optional>` on the dependency in B.

Please note that if C calls a method of B that needs libX, this will then fail.